# Can The Thing survive deep water, yet require oxygen?

Tags: marvel, the-thing

I've recently re-read the AvX: VS series. I noticed in #1 the brawl between The Thing and Namor, which happens in deep water. Thing seemed to have no issue with lack of air, and walked out of the water after the brawl, which must have required a lot of oxygen.

Yet in #3, he duels with Colossus/Juggernaut. When the fight goes out of the area with oxygen in it, The Thing collapses due to lack of air. Yet Colossus/Juggernaut was unaffected, perhaps due to also being the Juggernaut?

The main issue I have is that The Thing wins a fight in deep water without air, yet cannot win a fight on the moon without air. Is this an inconsistency, or some intentional difference between environments?

Comment: There's oxygen in water.

Comment: @JimmyShelter Ya, but humans don't normally breathe in water without diving apparatus.

Comment: @GrantPalin The Thing is not a normal human.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Let's call it inconsistent writing. I suspect since the Thing has never been adequately defined over the decades, most writers are not clear on his capacities besides having orange rock for skin and loving to yell "It's Clobbering Time" on any sot stupid enough to engage him in hand to hand combat. It isn't the air that is entirely the problem, by the way, it's his opponents. With air or without, Colossus the Juggernaut is a tough act to beat.

- Avengers vs Xmen (AvX) was totally fan pandering and the battles there were often inconsistent with previous information given to us on these characters.
- The Thing DOES require air but can hold his breath for up to a half hour with his increased lung capacity and reduced need for oxygen (he is after all, comprised mostly of living stone whose mechanics for repair are NEVER clearly defined.)
- This is out of the Marvel Handbook, so any underwater battle which takes less than a half an hour and doesn't require the Thing to go all out he may be able to hold his own for a while.
- Looking at the battle, the Thing does not appear to ever be distressed and even has the wherewithal to make jokes while fighting.

[image]

The battle between the Thing and Namor was a titanic one but only a fraction as difficult as the Thing vs Colossus the Juggernaut.

- The Juggernaut is much stronger than the Thing and much more durable.
- While the Thing may be a better fighter, he would ultimately be no match for the power of Colossus the Juggernaut who combines his already formidable osmium metal body with the nigh-limitless power of being an Avatar of Cyttorak.
- Knocking the Thing onto the unshielded lunar surface should have had the same effect as being underwater (nothing appreciable) and the Thing should have been able to continue to fight albeit poorly considering the beating he was getting from Colossus. Colossus would not be affected by the lack of oxygen in any way. He isn't called the Unstoppable Juggernaut for nothing!

[image]